# External user as record owner - implications?

Tags: sharing, customer-community, record-access-level

I wanted to ask about something that is bothering me. I once came across a statement that an **External User (for example, one with a Community Cloud license) should not be the owner of records** because it has many implications. As an example - Case record created from Experience Portal.

I tried searching the documentation to find out why, but I couldn't find anything. So, I'm asking for your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was following this question and was waiting for an answer.
But since there are no answers , I will try to answer this to the best of my knowledge.

**What happens if we try to make a Experience(a.k.a. Community) user as owner of case record?**

We get below error , stating invalid operation as below :
[image]
Same behaviour is observed for case and any other object which the external user has access.

Above behaviour is also stated in this community post - https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A84c5SAB

**What happens when an external user creates a Case/Account record through community ?**

As an example , if a Case is created from an Experience site , the external user becomes the case owner.

**What are the implications of record owned by an external user ?**

- For Cases, it grants the related contact and everyone in the role hierarchy access to the case record. ([Related article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_restrict_case_access.htm&type=5))
- For Accounts , external users can manage accounts. ([Related article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_external_managed_accounts.htm&type=5))

When an external user owns a record like Case , it gives implicit access to the users in hierarchy. Hence , it is advised to route cases to internal user and share the record via any external sharing mechanism.

Comment: Could you put your answer in order? You are confusing different users with different licences, and you are incorrectly stating that CC cannot be the owner of e.g. Case, which is not true.

Comment: @Adamo : Thank you for the feedback.I've edited my answer.
Also , if you read my answer , I never stated that CC user cannot be owner of Case/ Account record. In the first part of the answer , I just shared a screenshot of error when we try to assign a Case/Account to the CC user.
In the later part of the answer , I've shared the implications of a record (Case / Account) owned by a external(CC/ CC+) user.

Comment: Edited the answer with 1 typo.